# git-checkout older revision of a binary file without overwiting the working copy

Tags: git

I have a *binary* file (foo.bin) in my git repository.

How can I checkout an older version of this file without overwriting the file in my working copy?

Something like:

```
git checkout tag-name -- foo.bin > foo-tag-name.bin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You command was almost correct:

```
git show tag-name:foo.bin > foo-tag-name.bin
```

`git help show` also gives another example:

```
   git show next~10:Documentation/README
        Shows the contents of the file Documentation/README as they were
        current in the 10th last commit of the branch next.
```

That syntax is described in `git help gitrevisions`:

```
   <rev>:<path>, e.g. HEAD:README, :README, master:./README
       A suffix : followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given
       path in the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that `git show` can handle binary files as well.

Comment: Came across this just recently, and tried it, and it doesn't seem to work for binary files (which the original question asked for).   In my version of git (2.19.1), it outputs a small text file with the sha256 string, and version, but not a binary.

Answer (score 1):

`git show` is the command you're looking for:

```
git show tag-name:foo.bin > foo-tag-name.bin
```